# how to solve this equation containing "min"?

Tags: calculus, optimization

$$
xy=128,x+y=\min
$$

How to find $x$ and $y$ with the minimum sum?

This example is simple and can be done by brute forcing but I want to know what is the proper way of solving it.

How to solve other equations like this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\left(\frac{x+y}2\right)^2\ge xy$ is the simplest case of [AM-GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM_inequality) -- only two variables.

It can also be derived by noticing that $0\le (x-y)^2 =x^2-2xy+y^2$ $\Longrightarrow$ $x^2+y^2\ge 2xy$ $\Longrightarrow$ $(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2\ge 4xy$.

Either way, you get, for $x,y\ge0$,
$$x+y \ge 2\sqrt{xy} = 2\sqrt{128}=16\sqrt2.$$

---

If you allow $x$ and $y$ to be negative, you can get the sum to be arbitrarily low. Just try
$x=-128$, $y=-1$
$x=-1280$, $y=-1/10$
$x=-12800$, $y=-1/100$
etc.

Answer (score 2):

$xy = 128 \implies y = \frac{128}{x}$

so now

$x + y = x+ \frac{128}{x} = f(x)$

How do you minimize $f(x)$?

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

We have  $y=\frac{128}x,$

$$x+y=x+\frac{128}x=z\text{(say)}$$

$$\implies x^2-zx+128=0$$

As $x$ is real, the discriminant of the above quadratic equation must be $\ge0$

$$\implies z^2\ge 4\cdot1\cdot128=512=(16\sqrt2)^2$$

We know if $x^2\ge a^2$ either $x\ge a$ or $x\le-a$